# Can't connect to Azure MySQL flexible server, any ideas why?

Tags: azure, mysql-workbench, azure-mysql-database

I am trying to connect to the azure mysql flexible-server from MySQL workbench / azure-cli but have not been successful.

I have allowed connections to the server from my current IP. I followed the instructions on the Azure connections page and receive the error "unable to connect to localhost". I tried connecting from powershell using mysql command and receive the error 2003 (10060). I also tried connecting to server using azure-cli in docker container. I allowed connections to server from IP of container and logged in using "az login". I could run certain commands like "az mysql flexible-server db show" that would work, but when running "az mysql flexible-server connect ..." I would get timeout error. [[image: Attempt from docker container]](ht[image: attempt from MySQL workbench]tps://i.stack.imgur.com/cLZA5.png)

Comment: What does this powershell do: `Test-NetConnection <yourserver> -Port 3306` ? This checks the connection at the network layer. The error message is ambiguous. It shouldn't be trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: I also suggest you take docker caontainer out of the equation in the first instance - it adds complexity to the troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 0):

While connecting Azure MySQL Flexible server with My SQL Workbench, the errors shows that `unable to connect to localhost` check with the user name provided in the Azure MySQL and also check the server name while replacing it into `Hostname`.

Follow the below steps to connect Azure MySQL Flexible server with MySQL Workbench:

- Click on **`+`** which is beside `MySQL Connections` in MySQL Workbench.
  [image]
- Provide `Connection Name`, `Hostname`, `username` and `password` which you have given in Azure MySQL Flexible Server.
  [image]
- Click on `Test Connection` to check the connection if it is successful then it shows Successfully made the MySQL Connection as shown below.
  [image]
- Then it successfully opens MySQL Workbench as shown below.
  [image]

And also after creation of MySql Flexible server in Azure it shows how to connect with MySQL Workbench under settings in `connect` option and what values are need to replaced with as shown below.
[image]